# Issues in UITabBar with SideMenu

Tags: ios

I created tab bar controller programmatically in objective c and I need to implement the side bar menu.Is it possible to implement the side bar menu in tab bar controller?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.tabBarController =[[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    //Initialize View controller and speciality
    UIViewController *viewcontroller1=[[HomeView alloc]init];
    UIViewController *viewcontroller2=[[Speciality alloc]init];
    UIViewController *viewcontroller3=[[Activity alloc]init];
    UIViewController *viewcontroller4 =[[Notification alloc]init];
    UIViewController *viewcontroller5 =[[Profile alloc]init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewcontroller1,viewcontroller2,viewcontroller3,viewcontroller4,viewcontroller5, nil];
    self.window.rootViewController =self.tabBarController;
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.barTintColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:0.376 green:0.729 blue:0.318 alpha:1.000];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Download the library https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController

and copy the files `SWRevealViewController.h` & `SWRevealViewController.m`  to your project

in  `AppDelegate.h`

```
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"

@property (strong,nonatomic) SWRevealViewController *revealViewController;
```

in `AppDelegate.m`

```
self.revealViewController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc]initWithRearViewController:leftViewController frontViewController:tabBarController];
if ( self.revealViewController )
{
   UIButton  *button1 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 65, 80, 30)];
    [button1 setTitle:@"Side bar" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button1 setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button1 addTarget:self.revealViewController action:@selector(revealToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [tabBarController.view addSubview:button1];//if u hav navigation controller u can replace button1 with BarButtonItem
    [tabBarController.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
}
```